# Detecting C types limits ("limits.h") in python?

Tags: python, c, limit, ctypes

I've made a little test program in python to test some C functions in many cases. This python program use `ctypes` to import and use my C functions.

But I'd also like to test minimum and maximum values cases (`limits.h`'s `ULLONG_MAX` for instance).

But since some of these limits can be system dependant, I'd prefer to avoid hard coding it in my program; I'd rather dynamically get it.

Is it possible to get these limits values in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reference #defines in a C file from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147394/how-can-i-reference-defines-in-a-c-file-from-python)

Comment: Might worth reading: [\[SO\]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the closest you can get is

```
ctypes.sizeof(whatever_type)
```

which gives you the size of the type in bytes. For example, you can use `ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_int)` to figure out whether a byte is 4 bytes, 8, or some other weird number.

Comment: Or assume 2's complement and use a negative -1 value with the corresponding unsigned type, e.g. `c_uint(-1).value` for the unsigned limit, and divide the unsigned max by 2 to get the signed max.

Comment: @eryksun: All I've found in the docs about passing an out-of-range value is that "no overflow checking is done", so I don't know whether `c_uint(-1)` is actually supported.

Comment: No overflow checking means that it does overflow without raising an exception. That's what I'm depending on, and know from the source, but you're right that the docs are poorly worded.

Comment: @user2357112 Your solutions sounds really elegant! @eryksun's solution works on my system.
To get signed types limit values, a little trick is enough, for instance :
`ctypes.c_uint(-1).value // 2` for `INT_MAX` and `(-ctypes.c_uint(-1).value) // 2` for `INT_MIN`

Comment: @vmonteco, it'll work on any system supported by CPython. Setting the value of simple integer ctypes is implemented via `PyLong_AsUnsignedLong[Long]Mask` with a subsequent cast to the target C type. But the docs are less than clear.

Comment: @vmonteco - Thank you for the comment above. May I ask why -1 must be used to determine these values? My brief tests show that no other number can be used to determine the TYPE_MIN / TYPE_MAX values.  (I'm using bit shifting myself - but this seems more straight-forward.)