# python pack/unpack numbers specifyig number of bytes

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I'm trying to convert int numbers (>=0 && <2^32 of course) in Python into a 4 byte unsigned int representation and back.

As I understand the docs the sizes given in [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct-alignment) are a standard but the size is not guaranteed.. how can I make sure that I get 4 exactly bytes?

One way I found using ctypes:

`byte_repr=bytes(ctypes.c_uint32(data))`

Is this the most pythonic one there is? And what would be the way back (for this or any other solution)?

Comment: Unless you're serializing objects, if you care about how many bytes something is in Python, then you've already thrown "pythonic" out the window.

Comment: @user10987432 Well that's just not true.. If for example he's sending something over the network at a specified size, it is not "... throw(ing) pythonic out the window"

Comment: @maor10 If you're sending something over the network, that is "serializing an object" by definition.

Comment: Well anything in python is "an object" so that's a bit of a moot point. He's specifically asking about a number- converting a number to a binary representation is not "unpythonic", and it's a bit ridiculous to say that

Comment: What do you mean by "*the size is not guaranteed*" (for *struct*)?

Comment: @CristiFati I just read the paragraph again and found the statement "The ‘Standard size’ column refers to the size of the packed value in bytes when using standard size; that is, when the format string starts with one of '<', '>', '!' or '='. When using native size, the size of the packed value is platform-dependent." From this I actually just read "the size of the packed value is platform-dependent" so maybe this is already the solution

Comment: @user10987432 i'm "serializing" into a fixed size representation indeed. Have to squeeze my data into a QR code. You are right that usually it should not matter but for some applications it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `int` and `bytes` have the methods you need for that.

Note that I am calling `from_bytes` from the class `int` but it can be called from an `int` instance object:

```
>>> a = 2**32-1
>>> a.to_bytes(4, 'little')
b'\xff\xff\xff\xff'
>>> b = a.to_bytes(4, 'little')
>>> c = int.from_bytes(b, 'little')
>>> c
4294967295
>>> a
4294967295
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the mentioned interval, you're talking about ***unsigned int*s**. 
[[Python 3.Docs]: struct - Interpret strings as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#module-struct) works fine (well, on platforms (compilers) where **`sizeof(int) == 4`**). 
Since for a vast majority of environments the above is true, you can safely use it (unless you're positive that the code will run on an exotic platform, where the compiler used to build *Python* is different).

> ```
> >>> import struct
> >>>
> >>> bo = "<"  # byte order: little endian
> >>>
> >>> ui_max = 0xFFFFFFFF
> >>>
> >>> ui_max
> 4294967295
> >>> buf = struct.pack(bo + "I", ui_max)
> >>> buf, len(buf)
> (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff', 4)
> >>>
> >>> ui0 = struct.unpack(bo + "I", buf)[0]
> >>> ui0
> 4294967295
> >>>
> >>> i0 = struct.unpack(bo + "i", buf)[0]  # signed int
> >>> i0
> -1
> >>> struct.pack(bo + "I", 0)
> b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> >>>
> >>> struct.pack(bo + "I", ui_max + 1)
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> struct.error: argument out of range
> >>>
> >>> struct.unpack(bo + "I", b"1234")
> (875770417,)
> >>>
> >>> struct.unpack(bo + "I", b"123")  # 3 bytes buffer
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
> >>>
> >>> struct.unpack(bo + "I", b"12345")  # 5 bytes buffer
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
> ```

Related (remotely): [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475749/maximum-and-minimum-value-of-c-types-integers-from-python/52485502#52485502).

[[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) variant:

> ```
> >>> # Continuation of previous snippet
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>> ct_ui_max = ct.c_uint32(ui_max)
> >>>
> >>> ct_ui_max
> c_ulong(4294967295)
> >>>
> >>> buf = bytes(ct_ui_max)
> >>> buf, len(buf)
> (b'\xff\xff\xff\xff', 4)
> >>>
> >>> ct.c_uint32(ui_max + 1)
> c_ulong(0)
> >>>
> >>> ct.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(buf)
> c_ulong(4294967295)
> >>> ct.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(buf + b"\x00")
> c_ulong(4294967295)
> >>> ct.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(b"\x00" + buf)  # 0xFFFFFF00 (little endian)
> c_ulong(4294967040)
> >>>
> >>> ct.c_uint32.from_buffer_copy(buf[:-1])
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ValueError: Buffer size too small (3 instead of at least 4 bytes)
> ```

**Note**: @progmatico's answer is simpler and more straightforward as it doesn't involve any module other than *builtin* ([[Python 3.Docs]: Built-in Types - Additional Methods on Integer Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types)). As a side note, *sys.byteorder* could be used.