# Value to Assign to Missing Values in uint Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, missing-data, numpy-ndarray

A numpy array `z` is constructed from 2 Python lists `x` and `y` where values of `y` can be `0` and values of `x` are not continuously incrementing (i.e. values can be skipped).

Since `y` values can also be `0`, it will be confusing to assign missing values in `z` to be `0` as well.

What is the best practice to avoid this confusion?

```
import numpy as np

# Construct `z`
x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
y = [12, 34, 56, 0, 78, 0]
z = np.ndarray(max(x)+1).astype(np.uint32)  # missing values become 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    z[x[i]] = y[i]

print(z)        # [ 0 12 34 56  0  0  0  0 78  0  0  0  0  0]
print(z[4])     # missing value but is assigned 0
print(z[13])    # non-missing value but also assigned 0
```

Comment: Can you accept signed integers? What do you want to do with the missing values later?

Comment: @DavidHoffman Best to stick to unsigned integers, but it is probably beneficial to also know the solution when signed integers can be used. When a missing value is detected when reading from the array, a different logic may be used in the main program, such as raising an error or accessing the value at another index until a non-missing element is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You could typically assign `np.nan` or any other value for the non-existing indices in `x`.

Also, no need for the *for loop*. You can directly assign all values of `y` in one line, as I showed here.

However, since you are typecasting to *uint32*, you cannot use `np.nan` ([*why not?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan)). Instead, you could use a large number (*for example, `999999`*) of your choice, which by design, will not show up in `y`. For more details, please refer to the links shared in the **References** section below.

```py
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
y = [12, 34, 56, 0, 78, 0]
# cannot use np.nan with uint32 as np.nan is treated as a float
# choose some large value instead: 999999 
z = np.ones(max(x)+1).astype(np.uint32) * 999999 
z[x] = y
z

# array([999999,     12,     34,     56, 999999,      0, 999999, 999999,
#            78, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999,      0], dtype=uint32)
```

### References

- [Numpy integer nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708807/numpy-integer-nan)
- [Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475749/maximum-and-minimum-value-of-c-types-integers-from-python)

Comment: @athena-wisdom Does this help?

Comment: Why `y.copy()`?

Comment: How do you preserve the original `np.uint32` `dtype` after multiplying with `np.nan`? Seems like the numbers are now `np.float64`

Comment: @mathfux Good catch. That was a typo. Removed the `.copy()`. Thank you.

Comment: @AthenaWisdom Try now. You need a large value (such as 999999) that you don't expect to find in `y`, and assign it instead of `nan`, since `np.nan` is treated as a `float`.