# Problem in passing numpy array to a C function

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have the following C function:

```
int c_sum(const int *a, int len) {

    int c = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
        c += a[i];
    }
    return c;
}
```

After creating the shared lib with the following:

```
cc -fPIC -shared -o c_sum.so c_sum.c
```

I run the following Python code in Jupyter notebook

```
import numpy as np
import time
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("c_sum.so")
c_sum = lib.c_sum
c_sum.restype = c_int


a = np.random.randint(1,5,6)
print(a)

c = c_sum(c_void_p(a.ctypes.data), c_int(len(a)))
print(c)
```

It prints the following:

```
[1 4 3 1 2 2]
8
```

What might be the problem here? It prints the sum of the first 3 numbers. I tried random arrays of different lengths, it turns out that the code always sums the first half of the numbers in the array. Thanks.

Comment: 1st thing is: [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011).

Comment: Yes, I found that the problem is Python int is 4 bytes but C int is 2 bytes, when I change the type of the array from int to long it worked. But this seems to be an ad-hoc solution, I need to find a better way to handle this situtation.

Comment: Your comment (at least the 1st sentence) couldn't be more wrong. All I mentioned in mine is that you should specify *argtypes* and *restype* for your function.

Comment: You need to change the int type of your array. Try `a.astype(np.int32)` (or `np.int16` if your C int is really 16-bit).

Comment: @CristiFati I'm not referring to your comment. All I'm referring to is: yes, it is about a problem related to the number of bytes allocated for integer types in C.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to explain in an answer rather than in comments. It has nothing to do with different *int* sizes. Yes, the types do differ, but not in the way *OP* thinks, as the *int* array is a *NumPy* (which is written in *C* and *C++*) one. Check [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475749/maximum-and-minimum-value-of-c-types-integers-from-python/52485502#52485502) for more details on this topic.

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). 
Also listing [[NumPy]: C-Types Foreign Function Interface (numpy.ctypeslib)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#c-types-foreign-function-interface-numpy-ctypeslib) - convenience library for conversions between *NumPy* and *CTypes*.

*dll00.c*:

```c
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL00_EXPORT_API
#endif


#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif

DLL00_EXPORT_API int arrSum(const int *arr, int len);

#if defined(__cplusplus)
}
#endif


int arrSum(const int *arr, int len)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        s += arr[i];
    return s;
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ctypes as ct
import sys
import numpy as np


IntPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_int)

DLL_NAME = "./dll00.{:s}".format("dll" if sys.platform[:3].lower() == "win" else "so")


def main(*argv):
    dll00 = ct.CDLL(DLL_NAME)
    arrSum = dll00.arrSum
    arrSum.argtypes = (IntPtr, ct.c_int)
    arrSum.restype = ct.c_int

    a = np.random.randint(1, 5, 6)
    print(a, sum(a))

    datas = [
        np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(a),  # Using ctypeslib
        a.ctypes.data_as(IntPtr),  # Using manual conversion
        #IntPtr(ct.c_long(a.ctypes.data)),  # Original way - wrong
    ]
    for data in datas:
        res = arrSum(data, len(a))
        print("\n{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(arrSum.__name__, res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q070633293]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\pc032\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2019\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 >nul
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /MD /DDLL dll00.c  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:dll00.dll
> dll00.c
>    Creating library dll00.lib and object dll00.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> code00.py
> dll00.c
> dll00.dll
> dll00.exp
> dll00.lib
> dll00.obj
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> [2 2 2 3 4 4] 17
>
> arrSum returned: 17
>
> arrSum returned: 17
>
> Done.
> ```

Comment: If you're setting argtype for something that gets a numpy array as a pointer, I would suggest using numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer instead of a generic pointer type. You can check that a bunch of attributes and flags on the python object are correct.

Comment: @CJR: That's true, thanks for the suggestion, it could be `arrSum.argtypes = (np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.int32, ndim=1, flags='C_CONTIGUOUS'), ct.c_int)`, and the call, simply: `res = arrSum(a, len(a))`.