# Is there a way to pass a python array to a C function?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am currently learning how to call a C library from Python. I do not quite understand the proper way to pass an array from Python to a C function for computation and get the returned value back to Python.

Suppose that I have a C function, namely `cfun`, which takes an integer, dim, and an array, `double *a`, for computation and return the results to another array, `double *b`. In my Python routine, I have declared two arrays, arr1 and arr2 and I would like to tell the cfun to use the actual locations of the allocated memory of arr1 and arr2 for computation.

Is my `*.pyx` code which is shown below efficient enough for my purpose, whereas cfun is computationally expensive and is frequently called?

```py
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef extern from "header.h": 
    void cfun ( int dim, double *a, double *b ) 

def pyfun ( dim, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] arr1, np.ndarray[double,ndim=1] arr2 )

    cfun ( dim, <double*> arr1.data, <double*> arr2.data )
    return None
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lmammino/10ae9ad290809f172e6eb3b6957bd18c

This github page may help. It shows a simple example of how to run a C function with parameters called by python and then return the result to python

Comment: There are many examples, here are a couple that partially achieve what you;re after: [\[SO\]: Problem in passing numpy array to a C function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70634363/4788546), [\[SO\]: What is numpy.ctypeslib.as\_ctypes exacty doing (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505437/4788546), [\[SO\]: Boundary problems using a numpy kernel and padding on a matrix within a C functions called from python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74174207/4788546).

Comment: Python does not have a built-in array type. Did you mean that you have **lists**? Or were you talking about the standard library `array.array`, or a Numpy array, or something else?