# When I use ctypes.c_int() it returns a different number?

Tags: python, go, ctypes

> When I use the code below, it returns a different number.
>
> ```
> numb = 5000000000
> n = ctypes.c_int(numb)
> ```
>
> the number it converts : 705032703

**UPDATE**

now it doesn't give error. and performed the operation. However, the number it returns is still different. It should return the number I entered. but it does not return.

main.py

```
numb = 5000000000
n = ctypes.c_int64(numb)
x = hello_world(n)
print(x)
```

golang code that I converted to c code

main.go

```
package main

import "C"

func helloWorld(x int64) int64 {
    s := int64(1)
    for i := int64(1); i < x; i++ {
        s = i
    }
    return s
 }
```

Comment: The constructor accepts an optional integer initializer; no overflow checking is done.

Comment: [\[SO\]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes` exposes the C-compatible types, with `ctypes.c_int()` being an exposure of the signed `int` type, which could be 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the platform (or possibly even narrower or wider).

In your instance, your `c_int` is a 32-bit type, and a 32-bit signed int can hold the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`, or `4294967296` possible values.

So it can't hold your `5000000000` (5 billion) as-is, and it's implementation-defined how overflow is handled.

If you want to hold large numbers, it's recommended to used fixed-width types like [`c_int64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_int64) so you know exactly what you're dealing with, as `c_int` and `c_long` have some size guarantees but are otherwise implementation/platform specific.

Comment: n = ctypes.c_int64(numb) I used this and it returned a long type value I think I solved the problem. thank you very much.

Comment: @user14410167 yes, `c_int64` would work - I added another sentence to recommend the fixed-width types as you're using.

Answer (score 2):

5,000,000,000 is too large for a 32-bit integer.  You can see below it just truncates to 32 bits:

```py
>>> n=5000000000
>>> hex(n)
'0x12a05f200'         # 33 bits
>>> import ctypes
>>> hex(ctypes.c_int(n).value)
'0x2a05f200'          # dropped the 33rd bit
```

You can see the same thing by ANDing with a 32-bit mask:

```py
>>> n & 0xffffffff
705032704
```

Comment: How do you think I can convert the number 5000000000 to type c? What should I use for this? which type?

Comment: n = ctypes.c_int64(numb) I used this and it returned a long type value I think I solved the problem. thank you very much.