# quickly check that Python3 integer fits into C long or int

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

In Python2's C API there was `long PyInt_AS_LONG()` function which allowed a very quick creation of a C `long` from a Python2 `int`.

Is there a quick way to check, using Python3 C API, that an `int` (which is actually an arbitrary precision integer) fits into C `long`?

One can call `PyLong_AsLong()`, but this appears to do unnecessary work.  There ought to be a function to get the size of the memory block used to store the number, but I can't find anything in the docs.

This has to be done in C, so I can't directly use Python arithmetic comparison. Although I can, in principle, call [PyObject_RichCompare()](https://docs.python.org/3.10/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_RichCompare), it looks like an overkill.

Comment: I need to do this in C, so I can't just do `<`.

Comment: What is the "unnecessary work" you think `PyLong_AsLong()` is doing?  If it's just that you want a flag rather than an actual exception generated for out-of-range values - try `PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow()` instead.

Comment: I don't know how Python stores its integers. Thanks for pointing out `PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow` - I suspect it'll be much faster than `PyLong_AsLong`, as exceptions are slow.

Answer (score 1):

*PyLong_AsLong* code can be found at [[GitHub]: python/cpython - (v3.10.13) cpython/Objects/longobject.c#453](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.13/Objects/longobject.c#L453) and (as @jasonharper pointed out in a comment) uses *PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow* (which is right above it).

I created a test program.

*_mod00.c*:

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include "Python.h"

#define MOD_NAME "_mod00"


static PyObject* PyTestAsLongAndOverflow(PyObject *self, PyObject *iObj)
{
    int of;
    if (!PyLong_CheckExact(iObj)) {
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    PyLong_AsLongAndOverflow(iObj, &of);
    if (of) {
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}


static PyObject* PyTestAsLong(PyObject *self, PyObject *iObj)
{
    if (!PyLong_CheckExact(iObj)) {
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    PyLong_AsLong(iObj);
    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}


static PyObject* PyTestParseTuple(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    long l = 0;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "l", &l)) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    Py_RETURN_TRUE;
}


static PyMethodDef moduleMethods[] = {
    {"test_as_long_and_overflow", (PyCFunction)PyTestAsLongAndOverflow, METH_O, NULL},
    {"test_as_long", (PyCFunction)PyTestAsLong, METH_O, NULL},
    {"test_parse_tuple", (PyCFunction)PyTestParseTuple, METH_VARARGS, NULL},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL},  // Sentinel
};

static struct PyModuleDef moduleDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, MOD_NAME, NULL, -1, moduleMethods
};


PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit__mod00(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&moduleDef);
}
```

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import timeit

import _mod00 as mod


FUNCS = (
    mod.test_as_long_and_overflow,
    mod.test_as_long,
    mod.test_parse_tuple,
)


def test_acc():
    print("Test accuracy:")
    values = (
        None,
        False,
        3.141593,
        "",
        -1,
        0,
        1,
        sys.maxsize,
        sys.maxsize + 1,
        -sys.maxsize,
        -sys.maxsize - 1,
        -sys.maxsize - 2,
    )
    for value in values:
        print("  ({:s}) {:}{:s}:".format(value.__class__.__name__, value, " (hex: {:016X})".format(value) if isinstance(value, int) else ""))
        for func in FUNCS:
            print("    {:s}: {:}".format(func.__name__, func(value)))


def test_perf(count=10000000):
    print("\nTest performance:")
    values = (
        sys.maxsize,
        sys.maxsize + 1,
    )
    for value in values:
        print("  ({:s}) {:}{:s}:".format(value.__class__.__name__, value, " (hex: {:016X})".format(value) if isinstance(value, int) else ""))
        for func in FUNCS:
            print("    {:s}: {:.3f}s".format(func.__name__, timeit.timeit(lambda: func(value), number=count)))


def main(*argv):
    test_acc()
    test_perf()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@cfati-5510-0:/mnt/e/Work/Dev/StackExchange/StackOverflow/q076889790]> . ~/sopr.sh 
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  _mod00.c
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -shared -o _mod00.so _mod00.c
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> code00.py  _mod00.c  _mod00.so
> [064bit prompt]> 
> [064bit prompt]> python ./code00.py 
> Python 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Test accuracy:
>   (NoneType) None:
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: False
>   (bool) False (hex: 0000000000000000):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (float) 3.141593:
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: False
>   (str) :
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: False
>   (int) -1 (hex: -000000000000001):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) 0 (hex: 0000000000000000):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) 1 (hex: 0000000000000001):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) 9223372036854775807 (hex: 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) 9223372036854775808 (hex: 8000000000000000):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: False
>   (int) -9223372036854775807 (hex: -7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) -9223372036854775808 (hex: -8000000000000000):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: True
>     test_as_long: True
>     test_parse_tuple: True
>   (int) -9223372036854775809 (hex: -8000000000000001):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: False
>     test_as_long: False
>     test_parse_tuple: False
>
> Test performance:
>   (int) 9223372036854775807 (hex: 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: 0.819s
>     test_as_long: 0.828s
>     test_parse_tuple: 1.140s
>   (int) 9223372036854775808 (hex: 8000000000000000):
>     test_as_long_and_overflow: 0.813s
>     test_as_long: 1.128s
>     test_parse_tuple: 1.587s
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- I also tested conversion via *PyArg_ParseTuple* (but that's slower due to tuple operations performed behind the scene by the runtime)
- You were correct, setting exceptions adds some overhead
- Values may vary depending on platform / architecture: [[SO]: Maximum and minimum value of C types integers from Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485502/4788546)